# SqlDataReader inside a loop in vb.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sqldatareader

I m trying to insert/update multi-records and return the records after change in a table and I m using the following code,

```
Using cmd As New SqlCommand("TblRegJoinDynHdlr", con)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Dim Data = PtRegData(0).PartnerData
    For i As Integer = 0 To Data.Count - 1
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Data(i).RecID)) Then
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Data(i).RecID)
        End If
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Data(i).PtFilenum)) Then
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ptfilenum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ptfilenum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Data(i).PtFilenum)
        End If
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Data(i).PrtFilenum)) Then
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@prfilenum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@prfilenum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Data(i).PrtFilenum)
        End If
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PrtStatus", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (Data(i).PrtStatus)
        con.Open()
        Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While sdr.Read()
                Prtdata.Add(New PartnerData() With { _
                 .RecID = sdr("RecID").ToString(), _
                 .PrtFilenum = sdr("PrtFilenum").ToString(), _
                 .PtFilenum = sdr("PtFilenum").ToString(), _
                 .FullName = sdr("FullName").ToString(), _
                 .PrtStatus = sdr("PrtStatus").ToString(), _
                .DOB = sdr("DOB").ToString() _
                })
            End While
        End Using
        con.Close()
    Next

    con.Dispose()
End Using
```

**My Problem** 
If I leave the SqlDataReader inside the loop, all records are updated properly but I get the data as **n x 2** and if I leave it outside the loop I get my data but records are not updated/inserted properly
Any help please?

Comment: It's a bit confusing, but I think inside your loop you are adding the return of the insert to the same collection used in the loop, duplicating your data. 

The ExecuteReader is necessary ? Couldn't you use ExecuteNonQuery? At least, you shouldn't add the result in the same collection used by the loop.

Comment: @DennesTorres, yes I need the reader, I was doing ExecuteNonQuery before but then I need to populate a list so I used a reader

Comment: I cant use the loop for building the list, I need to read some data from the server upon data insert,,, is it possible to work around it with this example, because I  add a new procedure just to read data separate form the loop function

Comment: There is something confuse with your code. If you need to populate a list, could it be a different list ? It seems you are adding new itens to the same list you are using in the loop, although I'm not sure about this

Comment: so the "new" in  Prtdata.Add(New PartnerData() ,,,, does not sanitize the list and start adding from the beginning ?

Comment: I built another list, still getting the same problem,,, its the loop

Comment: with 'using', try to create variable of type object and add your values within variable.

Comment: @FabianoCarvalho, thanks for your input, could you please show me an example

Comment: @AhmadAbuMaizar within while do this


Dim DataValues As Object() = New Object(5) {} 

column(0) = column1
column(1) = column2
column(2) = column3
column(3) = column4
column(4) = column5

rowsArray.Add(column)

Answer (score -1):

before closing your connection close your reader, that is to say before going to the next round you must close your reader

```
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("TblRegJoinDynHdlr", con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Dim Data = PtRegData(0).PartnerData
        For i As Integer = 0 To Data.Count - 1
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Data(i).RecID)) Then
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
            Else
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Data(i).RecID)
            End If
            If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Data(i).PtFilenum)) Then
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ptfilenum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
            Else
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ptfilenum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Data(i).PtFilenum)
            End If
            If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Data(i).PrtFilenum)) Then
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@prfilenum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
            Else
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@prfilenum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Data(i).PrtFilenum)
            End If
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PrtStatus", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (Data(i).PrtStatus)
            con.Open()
            Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While sdr.Read()
                    Prtdata.Add(New PartnerData() With { _
                     .RecID = sdr("RecID").ToString(), _
                     .PrtFilenum = sdr("PrtFilenum").ToString(), _
                     .PtFilenum = sdr("PtFilenum").ToString(), _
                     .FullName = sdr("FullName").ToString(), _
                     .PrtStatus = sdr("PrtStatus").ToString(), _
                    .DOB = sdr("DOB").ToString() _
                    })
                End While
            End Using
    sdr.close() 'This code added
            con.Close()
        Next

    con.Dispose()
End Using
```